# troubleshoot pcsd ping resource on RHEL

Tags: linux, ping, redhat-enterprise-linux, cluster

we have configured ping resource monitor using REDHAT pcsd daemon.

In general - we get to error in /var/log/messages pointing to ping issue for specific entity (NAS server IP in this case). However we fail to get further information.

I want to understand how we can debug such cases to understand situation further ? Any pointers, experiences would be of great help.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Figured out following information even though it is trivial.

1. Sequential analysis of /var/log/messages
2. using journalctl -xr command
3. checking similar info in other node which is part of same cluster

Hope this helps to other people